# Finding a way not to compute a celery task twice

Tags: python, celery

I have 5 celery tasks:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def a(task, results={}):
    return {"key": "A"}

@app.task(bind=True)
def b(task, results={}):
    return {"key": "B"}

@app.task(bind=True)
def c(task, results={}):
    return {"key": "C"}

@app.task(bind=True)
def d(task, results={}):
    return {"key": "D"}

@app.task(bind=True)
def e(task, results={}):
    return {"key": "E"}
```

My goal is to execute them this way:

[image]

- d should take the outputs of a and b
- e should take the outputs of b and c

Here's my way of formulating it:

```
celery_graph = group(
    [
        group(
            [
                a.s(),
                b.s(),
            ]
        )
        | d.s(),
        group(
            [
                b.s(),
                c.s(),
            ]
        )
        | e.s(),
    ]
)
res = celery_graph.delay()
```

It works, but this calls task b twice. I'm looking for a way to keep this flow, but to call b only once.

NB: This is a minimal example